# What is the word whose meaning is to "oversimplify a complex issue; often incorrectly?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't think of the word and it's been bothering me for some time now. I have attempted to reverse search it, to no avail. If someone could oblige me with the word whose definition means to oversimplify an often complex issue, I would most appreciate it!

Comment: umm, that's what oversimplify means. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oversimplify

Comment: I agree with @dnagirl Can you explain how oversimplify is not the term you seek?

Comment: Minimize:  - To represent as having the least degree of importance, value, or size.

Comment: Also see linked questions [What’s a common phrase that means “To put it simply though not 100% correctly”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/210275) and [A word for “to make something bland and boring”](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/195304)

Comment: How can this be marked as duplicate? It clearly has very different answers.

Comment: facile *adj* (especially of a theory or argument) appearing neat and comprehensive only by ignoring the true complexities of an issue; superficial.

Comment: "Reductive" is a great word (and is the one I couldn't think of, prompting my Google search that landed me here. I used trivialize, but later remembered reductive and figured I'd add it here in case anyone else is looking (or I forget again and come back).

Answer (score 4):

To **dumb down** something.

**Dumbing down**:

> - Become less intellectually challenging; [OD](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dumb?q=dumbing%20down#dumb__20)
> - The act of taking a product and watering down elements of it to make it appeal to a broader mass market. This often damages or destroys the very elements that gave the product any appeal in the first place; [UD](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dumbing%20down)

Comment: And melding the two transitively means 'make a complex issue seem more simple, usually ending up with an unsatisfactory explanation'.

Answer (score 3):

To **trivialize** is to make something seem less important or serious than it really is. It can be extended to mean "oversimplify".

Comment: "Trivialise" is a great single-word choice, but it's less commonly used in a purely technical context. Example: "I don't want to trivialise this issue with a five-minute soundbite." would be fine if you're discussing geopolitics, but sounds weird if you're discussing string theory. In the latter case, I would say something else, e.g. "The theory is too involved for me to go into sufficient detail in just five minutes, so let's hold discussion over."

Comment: Isn't geopolitics a complex issue?

Comment: I never said it wasn't. But it's not a purely *technical* issue, in the narrow sense of something related to mathematics or hard science. I'm saying that the word "trivialise" is probably less suitable in the latter contexts (but fine for something like geopolitics or philosophy).

Answer (score 0):

To **[gloss](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gloss)** something means to provide a brief explanation of an obscure word of expression, and the word is commonly extended to ideas as as well. Of course, a brief explanation of a complex subject can't help but oversimplify it, otherwise it wouldn't be brief.

Comment: Most commonly used as "gloss over".